# how to get CURL values inside mvc3?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, curl

Am new for the MVC.Am using the following program using asp.net MVC3 with sql server 2005.I use the following code it was work properly.And my question is how to change this program like ,how to get the values from CURL(php) instead of signup form values and add that values into the sql server 2005?

```
UserManager.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MvcDemo.Models.DB;
using MvcDemo.Models.ViewModels;

namespace MvcDemo.Models
{
    public class UserManager
    {
        private UserView obj = new UserView();

        public void Add(UserView user)
        {
            obj.FirstName = user.FirstName;

            DB.Signup sysUser = new Signup();
            sysUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            sysUser.LastName = user.LastName;
            sysUser.Contactnumber = Int32.Parse(user.ContactNumber);
            sysUser.LoginID = user.LoginID;
            sysUser.Password = user.Password;
            obj.AddToSysUsers(sysUser);
                      }

                }
}

AccountController.cs


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using MvcDemo.Models.ViewModels;
using MvcDemo.Models;


namespace MvcDemo.Controllers
{

    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult SignUp()
        {
            return View("SignUp");
        }




        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignUp(UserView user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

                        userManager.Add(user);
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.FirstName, false);
                        return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(user);
            }

            return View(user);
        }
    }
}

Userview.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;



namespace MvcDemo.Models.ViewModels
{

    public class UserView
    {


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Login ID")]
        public string LoginID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }



        public void AddToSysUsers(DB.Signup sysUser)
        {
            try
            {
                string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["traineeEntities"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(con);
                co.Open();
                String str = "Insert into Signup values('"+sysUser.FirstName+"','"+sysUser.LastName+"',"+sysUser.Contactnumber+",'"+sysUser.LoginID+"','"+sysUser.Password+"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, co);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Message=Error Creating User: User already exists
            }

        }
    }
}

Signup.cshtml

@model MvcDemo.Models.ViewModels.UserView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SignUp";
}

<h2>Sign-Up</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserView</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Return to Home page","Index", "Home")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understandingw what you actually want to do. However, if I understand you correct, you want to submit the signup form via PHP and cURL. This is how you would submit a HTTP post using cURL:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'FirstName' => 'The firstname value',
    'LastName ' => 'The lastname value',
    'ContactNumber ' => 'The contactnumber value',
    'LoginID ' => 'The loginid value',
    'Password ' => 'The password value'
);

$post = http_build_query($data);

$url = 'http://url_to_your_server/Account/SignUp/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: how can i post the values(parameters) in Curl and how can I get that values in mvc?

Comment: Use the snippet i posted to post the values to your MVC Controller. In your `SignUp` action, you can access each parameter using `user.FirstName`, `user.LastName` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by getting the sign up form variables, you should easily be able to do that from the model you passed in to your action.

If you mean, how do you get the outside values that don't exist in the model, you would need to use.  The `Request` property.

```
public ActionResult Register(...) {
    var x = Request.Form["your form value here"] // for forms
    var y = Request.QueryString["your query string value here"] // for query strings
    var z = Request.Headers["for headers"] // for headers
    ... etc ...
}
```

If you can further clarify your question you might get some better answers, as of right now we are unclear about your goals.